# Apply StringIndexer to several columns in a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe

```
+-------+--------------+----+----+
|address|          date|name|food|
+-------+--------------+----+----+
|1111111|20151122045510| Yin|gre |
|1111111|20151122045501| Yin|gre |
|1111111|20151122045500| Yln|gra |
|1111112|20151122065832| Yun|ddd |
|1111113|20160101003221| Yan|fdf |
|1111111|20160703045231| Yin|gre |
|1111114|20150419134543| Yin|fdf |
|1111115|20151123174302| Yen|ddd |
|2111115|      20123192| Yen|gre |
+-------+--------------+----+----+
```

that I want to transform to use with pyspark.ml. I can use a StringIndexer to convert the name column to a numeric category:

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="name", outputCol="name_index").fit(df)
df_ind = indexer.transform(df)
df_ind.show()
+-------+--------------+----+----------+----+
|address|          date|name|name_index|food|
+-------+--------------+----+----------+----+
|1111111|20151122045510| Yin|       0.0|gre |
|1111111|20151122045501| Yin|       0.0|gre |
|1111111|20151122045500| Yln|       2.0|gra |
|1111112|20151122065832| Yun|       4.0|ddd |
|1111113|20160101003221| Yan|       3.0|fdf |
|1111111|20160703045231| Yin|       0.0|gre |
|1111114|20150419134543| Yin|       0.0|fdf |
|1111115|20151123174302| Yen|       1.0|ddd |
|2111115|      20123192| Yen|       1.0|gre |
+-------+--------------+----+----------+----+
```

How can I transform several columns with StringIndexer (for example, `name` and `food`, each with its own `StringIndexer`) and then use [VectorAssembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606294/create-feature-vector-programmatically-in-spark-ml-pyspark) to generate a feature vector? Or do I have to create a `StringIndexer` for each column?

** EDIT **: This is not a dupe because I need to to this programatically for several data frames with different column names. I can't use `VectorIndexer` or `VectorAssembler` because the columns are not numerical.

** EDIT 2**: A tentative solution is

```
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").fit(df).transform(df) for column in df.columns ]
```

where I create a list now with three dataframes, each identical to the original plus the transformed column. Now I need to join then to form the final dataframe, but that's very inefficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode and assemble multiple features in PySpark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982425/encode-and-assemble-multiple-features-in-pyspark)

Comment: Similar but not really. He's doing one column at a time for each string indexer and I need to do to several columns at the same time, without doing each separated

Comment: Then it is not possible. What would be even the output?

Comment: OK, that's what I was looking for. I will code an UDF then.

Comment: Don't you want some more like `CountVectroizer`?

Comment: Yeah, would be similar to sklearn `CountVectorizer`, but for several columns, no a list in a column.

Comment: You could gather columns with `array("some_col", "other_col")` and use `CountVectorizer` but I don't think it really make that much sense.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The best way that I've found to do it is to combine several `StringIndex` on a list and use a `Pipeline` to execute them all:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").fit(df) for column in list(set(df.columns)-set(['date'])) ]


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
df_r = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)

df_r.show()
+-------+--------------+----+----+----------+----------+-------------+
|address|          date|food|name|food_index|name_index|address_index|
+-------+--------------+----+----+----------+----------+-------------+
|1111111|20151122045510| gre| Yin|       0.0|       0.0|          0.0|
|1111111|20151122045501| gra| Yin|       2.0|       0.0|          0.0|
|1111111|20151122045500| gre| Yln|       0.0|       2.0|          0.0|
|1111112|20151122065832| gre| Yun|       0.0|       4.0|          3.0|
|1111113|20160101003221| gre| Yan|       0.0|       3.0|          1.0|
|1111111|20160703045231| gre| Yin|       0.0|       0.0|          0.0|
|1111114|20150419134543| gre| Yin|       0.0|       0.0|          5.0|
|1111115|20151123174302| ddd| Yen|       1.0|       1.0|          2.0|
|2111115|      20123192| ddd| Yen|       1.0|       1.0|          4.0|
+-------+--------------+----+----+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I have an iteration loop with reassignments inside. Ugliest code in the universe.. Guess it's time to invest a little effort and switch to `Pipelines` once and for all!

Comment: Do you really need to `fit` in `indexers`? You are running `fit` in the `pipeline` anyway.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I found this is no difference with for-loop. I still had multiple spark-job as for-loop

Answer (score 6):

With PySpark 3.0+ this is now easier and you can use the `inputCols` and `outputCols` options:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#stringindexer

```
class pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer(
    inputCol=..., 
    outputCol=..., 
    inputCols=..., 
    outputCols=..., 
    handleInvalid='error', 
    stringOrderType='frequencyDesc'
)
```

Comment: Your link is broken. Also it would be great to see an example on how to use these new options here.

Comment: Link is fixed :)

Comment: @NicScozzaro thank you, I didn't recognize that there is arguments for multiple columns.

Answer (score 4):

I can offer you the following solution. It is better to use pipelines for these kind of transformations on larger data sets. They also make your code a lot easier to follow and understand. You can add more stages to the pipelines if you need. For example add an encoder.

```
#create a list of the columns that are string typed
categoricalColumns = [item[0] for item in df.dtypes if item[1].startswith('string') ]

#define a list of stages in your pipeline. The string indexer will be one stage
stages = []

#iterate through all categorical values
for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:
    #create a string indexer for those categorical values and assign a new name including the word 'Index'
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = categoricalCol, outputCol = categoricalCol + 'Index')

    #append the string Indexer to our list of stages
    stages += [stringIndexer]

#Create the pipeline. Assign the satges list to the pipeline key word stages
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
#fit the pipeline to our dataframe
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
#transform the dataframe
df= pipelineModel.transform(df)
```

Please have a look at my [reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-with-pyspark-and-mllib-solving-a-binary-classification-problem-96396065d2aa)

Answer (score 1):

To Apply StringIndexer to several columns in a PySpark Dataframe
for spark 2.4.7

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol="F1", outputCol="F1Index") , StringIndexer(inputCol="F5", outputCol="F5Index")]


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
DF6 = pipeline.fit(DF5).transform(DF5)

DF6.show()
```