# How to use string variables in VectorAssembler in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, random-forest

I want to run Random Forests algorithm on Pyspark. It is mentioned in the [Pyspark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) that VectorAssembler accepts only numerical or boolean datatypes. So, if my data contains Stringtype variables, say names of cities, should I be one-hot encoding them in order to proceed further with Random Forests classification/regression?

Here is the code I have been trying, input file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0bAi7hOBAFcFgtUEdpLUFDQkk/view):

```
train=sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('filename')
drop_list = ["Country", "Carrier", "TrafficType","Device","Browser","OS","Fraud","ConversionPayOut"]
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
train = train.withColumn("ConversionPayOut", train["ConversionPayOut"].cast("double"))#only this variable is actually double, rest of them are strings
junk = train.select([column for column in train.columns if column in drop_list])
transformed = assembler.transform(junk)
```

I keep getting the errror that `IllegalArgumentException: u'Data type StringType is not supported.'`

P.S.: Apologies for asking a basic question. I come from R background. In R, when we do Random Forests, there is no need to convert the categorical variables into numeric variables.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942233/apply-stringindexer-to-several-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe) that can also be useful. You just need to concat the `indexers` into your pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should use [StringIndexer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer), maybe together with [OneHotEncoder](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder). You can find more information on these two in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Following is the example -
Schema
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- workclass: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fnlwgt: double (nullable = true)
 |-- education: string (nullable = true)
 |-- education-num: double (nullable = true)
 |-- marital-status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- occupation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- relationship: string (nullable = true)
 |-- race: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sex: string (nullable = true)
 |-- capital-gain: double (nullable = true)
 |-- capital-loss: double (nullable = true)
 |-- hours-per-week: double (nullable = true)
 |-- native-country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- income: string (nullable = true)

        // Deal with Categorical Columns
        // Transform string type columns to string indexer 
        val workclassIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("workclass").setOutputCol("workclassIndex")
        val educationIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("education").setOutputCol("educationIndex")
        val maritalStatusIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("marital-status").setOutputCol("maritalStatusIndex")
        val occupationIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("occupation").setOutputCol("occupationIndex")
        val relationshipIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("relationship").setOutputCol("relationshipIndex")
        val raceIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("race").setOutputCol("raceIndex")
        val sexIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("sex").setOutputCol("sexIndex")
        val nativeCountryIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("native-country").setOutputCol("nativeCountryIndex")
        val incomeIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("income").setOutputCol("incomeIndex")

        // Transform string type columns to string indexer 
        val workclassEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("workclassIndex").setOutputCol("workclassVec")
        val educationEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("educationIndex").setOutputCol("educationVec")
        val maritalStatusEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("maritalStatusIndex").setOutputCol("maritalVec")
        val occupationEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("occupationIndex").setOutputCol("occupationVec")
        val relationshipEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("relationshipIndex").setOutputCol("relationshipVec")
        val raceEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("raceIndex").setOutputCol("raceVec")
        val sexEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("sexIndex").setOutputCol("sexVec")
        val nativeCountryEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("nativeCountryIndex").setOutputCol("nativeCountryVec")
        val incomeEncoder = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("incomeIndex").setOutputCol("label")

    // Assemble everything together to be ("label","features") format
        val assembler = (new VectorAssembler()
          .setInputCols(Array("workclassVec", "fnlwgt", "educationVec", "education-num", "maritalVec", "occupationVec", "relationshipVec", "raceVec", "sexVec", "capital-gain", "capital-loss", "hours-per-week", "nativeCountryVec"))
          .setOutputCol("features"))

 ///////////////////////////////
    // Set Up the Pipeline ///////
    /////////////////////////////
    import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

    val lr = new LogisticRegression()

    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(workclassIndexer, educationIndexer, maritalStatusIndexer, occupationIndexer, relationshipIndexer, raceIndexer, sexIndexer, nativeCountryIndexer, incomeIndexer, workclassEncoder, educationEncoder, maritalStatusEncoder, occupationEncoder, relationshipEncoder, raceEncoder, sexEncoder, nativeCountryEncoder, incomeEncoder, assembler, lr))

    // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
    val model = pipeline.fit(training)
```