# How to match and replace in PySpark when columns contain vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark

I am trying to do a RandomForest Regression in Pyspark. Because most of variables are categorical with many factor levels, I had to string index them, one-hot encode and create a column of feature vectors using Vectorassembler. The output of Vectorassembler is the creation of a 'features' column in the training dataframe. Let's just call this dataframe as `train_OHE` after doing all the above transformations.

My code works fine till there.

Now when I run the randomforest regressor, there seems to be a strange error. `scala.MatchError: [null,(1598,[0,2,234,274,295,1596],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)`

When I run `train_OHE.show()`, all of the first 20 elements in the 'features' column, look like `[1598,[0,2,234,274,295,1596],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]]` - which is acceptable because of the sparse vector representation.

I think it is because of the extra `null` element somewhere in one of the rows.

So,
My question is how do I find out which row in my dataframe is causing this problem. Had it been a nomral string, I would have used `train_OHE['features'].like('%null%')`. In this case of sparse vector elements, how can find out this malfunctioning row? I tried `train_OHE['features'].split(',').like('%null%')` but errors throw up.

Comment: Probably `label` in `train_OHE` is missing. Can you check that? Also pls share your code snippet otherwise suggestion will only be based on assumption.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @Shibani no, I could not

Comment: So I figured the issue out in my case. It was because the "label" column in my input dataset was null for a few rows of data.

Comment: @Shibani: I see.. Thanks for sharing the information.