# Convert all nominal variables to categorical variables in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I'm just after a way to convert all the `String` type variables in my PySpark dataframe to categorical variables so I can run a decision tree on the dataframe. I can't use pandas and can only use PySpark libraries due to resource constraints. I've identified `VectorIndexer` as a possible solution, however, I don't understand how to convert all `String` type columns which the [documentation](http://takwatanabe.me/pyspark/generated/generated/pyspark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer.html) says is possible.

Could somebody help me with the syntax on how to do that? I'm after something like this:

```
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(inputCol=<list of input columns>, outputCol=<list of output columns>, maxCategories=10).fit(df)
```

or letting the `VectorIndexer` figure out which ones need vectoring on it's own, which the documentation seems to indicate that it can do.

```
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(df, maxCategories=10).fit(df)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VectorIndexer` takes a column of vector type as input, however, it sounds like you have a column with strings. In this case I would recommend to use `StringIndexer` and `OneHotEncoder`.

The `StringIndexer` will take a string column of labels to a column of label indices (doubles). The `OneHotEncoder` will then convert this column into multiple columns representing each category, to use as categorical features.

Afterwards, all these features can be combined into a single vector with an `VectorAssembler`. I would recommend the use of a pipeline to put all the stages together with the classifier.

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html) is the documentation of the different available feature transformations as well as examples of how they work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I kinda figured I messed up with that too. Could you also suggest how I can convert all columns? I tried passing column names as a list to inputCol argument but that resulted in an error. The reason is that I have some 50 odd string columns that needs converting and don't want to do everything by hand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @words_of_wisdom You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944716/7579547) answer that uses a pipeline to do the converting of multiple columns at once.