# Apply StringIndexer to change columns in a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark. I want to apply StringIndexer to change the value of the column to index.
I checked this post:
[Apply StringIndexer to several columns in a PySpark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942233/apply-stringindexer-to-several-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

This solution will create a new column rather than updating the input column. Is there a way to update the currrent column? I tried to use the same name for input and output, but it does not work.

```
label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol ="WindGustDir", outputCol = "WindGustDir_index")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply update that column. But what you can do is

- create a new column using the StringIndexer
- delete the original column
- rename the new column with the name of the original column

You can use this code

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


df = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 2], ['b', 5]], ['WindGustDir', 'value'])
df.show()
# +-----------+-----+
# |WindGustDir|value|
# +-----------+-----+
# |          a|    1|
# |          b|    1|
# |          c|    2|
# |          b|    5|
# +-----------+-----+

# 1. create new column
label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol ="WindGustDir", outputCol = "WindGustDir_index")
label_stringIdx_model = label_stringIdx.fit(df)
df = label_stringIdx_model.transform(df)

# 2. delete original column
df = df.drop("WindGustDir")

# 3. rename new column
to_rename = ['WindGustDir_index', 'value']
replace_with = ['WindGustDir', 'value']
mapping = dict(zip(to_rename, replace_with))
df = df.select([F.col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in to_rename])

df.show()

# +-----------+-----+
# |WindGustDir|value|
# +-----------+-----+
# |        1.0|    1|
# |        0.0|    1|
# |        2.0|    2|
# |        0.0|    5|
# +-----------+-----+
```